# When does $x \in \bar A$ implies that there is a sequence in $A$ that converges to $x$?

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres' *Topology*, he proves that in a first countable space $X$:

$(P)$: For any subset $A \subseteq X$ and any $x \in \bar A$, then there is a sequence $x_n$ with each $x_i \in A$ such that $x_n \to x$.

Does $(P)$ imply that $X$ is first countable? If not, does $(P)$ coincide with any well known class of spaces? I thought maybe it could coincide with sequential spaces, but I haven't been able to prove that either.

Comment: Spaces in which the closure of a set coincides with its sequential closure are called [Fréchet-Urysohn spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet%E2%80%93Urysohn_space).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thanks, you can post that as an answer if you want.

Comment: Too short to be an answer. Someone may post it and given an example of such a space that is not first countable, which would be a better answer.

Comment: Answers to many such questions can be answered by querying the [pi-Base](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000080).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you describe is Fréchet-Urysohn. This is a necessary but not sufficient property for first-countability: [https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Fr%C3%A9chet%20Urysohn%2B~First%20Countable](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Fr%C3%A9chet%20Urysohn%2B%7EFirst%20Countable)